# Spanish version of GPT on LTS 18.0.4

Tags: 18.04, lts, gpt

When I run gpt I get the following help message:

```
Modo de uso: gpt [opções] algoritmos...

Opções:
   -v            mostra versão do programa
   -h            mostra esse texto
   -o <arquivo>  compila e salva programa como <arquivo>
   -t <arquivo>  salva o código em linguagem C como <arquivo>
   -s <arquivo>  salva o código em linguagem Assembly como <arquivo>
   -i            interpreta o algoritmo
   -d            exibe dicas no relatório de erros

   Maiores informações no manual.
```

I'm actually unsure what GPT is, I confused it with gdisk for a second and tried running `gpt /dev/disk`, but I got some Spanish error messages.

Is this expected behavior ? I'm not complaining about Ubuntu being multi lingual, it just seems strange. The version I'm running as given by `uname -a`is: `Linux clickhouse_2 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 13 08:44:47 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: That's Portuguese not Spanish. The languages are notoriously similar (in their written forms), see [Jacques Eliacin François Marie Paganel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Paganel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `apt-cache show gpt`

> Description-en: G-Portugol is a portuguese structured programming
>   language  G-Portugol is a portuguese structured programming language,
>   based on the  popular, freeform, pseudocode known as portugol. The
>   compiler features  native compilation, translation to C code, and
>   interpretation of algorithms.

So it's not really a "Spanish version" of a package

Comment: Ah... fair enough, should have read a bit more into what it does. I did see the word "compile" but I kind of assumed it was a low level gpt related utility and the help page might have been buggy. Guess I should always man page these things.